# Spring MVC returns jsp as text/plain content type

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a problem with Spring MVC and jsp webpage.

When I request a webpage, it returns as *text/plain* by default. I tried setting the *content type* as *text/html* manually at the `HttpServletResponse` controller, and the web browser reconigzes it, showing it correctly BUT encoding the jsp tags at the body. Example:

JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Error 405 ******* </title>
    </head>
    <body> asdasdsasad </body>
</html>
```

Browser receives:

```
<html>
   <body>&lt;%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%&gt;

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using Spring Boot and java web based annotation for configuration. Also, I'm using `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and I found that the problem is solved by mapping the sevlet from "/*" to "/".

Because of the java annotation, I had to override the dispatchedServlet (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/91#issuecomment-27626036) and the configuration class is:

```
@Configuration
public class DispatcherConfiguration {

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet());
    registration.addUrlMappings("/");
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);

    System.out.println("~~~~~~~ Servlet regristated " + registration.getServletName());
    return registration;

}

@Bean
public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
    return new DispatcherServlet();
}
```

Notice that I'm using the `@Bean`  annotation missfollowing the previous comment link, because if not, Spring boot throws an exception. But even if not using the bean annotation, and using an xml the main problem is still here).

This is the Spring MVC configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("es.sfacut")
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login"); 
    registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
}

// Maps resources path to webapp/resources
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/images/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/imgs/**")
        .addResourceLocations(Constant.RESOURCE_IMAGES_PATH);
}

@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
// resolver.setContentType("text/html");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    // Size in bytes
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(1752300);
    return resolver;
}

}
```

Main class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("es.sfacut")
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class TelocomproMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TelocomproMain.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/")  
public class CategoryController {
    @RequestMapping(value="test4", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
    public ModelAndView pageTest4(HttpServletResponse response) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("elovendo/index");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return model;
    }
}
```

Application.properties:

```
#View resolver
spring.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/views/
spring.view.suffix= .jsp
```

Not sure if I'm missing something, I'll post everything you need.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are aware that there are [limitations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations) on using JSP with Spring Boot and you are taking that into consideration/account?

Comment: I always believed error 405 was *Method Not Allowed*... :)

Comment: Your configuration is also configuration to much interfering with Spring Boot. Remove `@EnableWebMvc`, remove the view resolver and default servlet handling. For view resolving add `spring.view.prefix` and `spring.view.suffix` to the `application.properties` file and Spring Boot will configure a `InternalResourceViewResolver` for you. `/Resources` is already mapped for you by Spring Boot. Also I'm wondering why would you need to register a servlet yourself as Spring Boot already takes care of that. Post your starter class.

Comment: I added the main class to the question, the controller and the application.properties. I know I have a lot of errors in my code, I'm just learning Spring and this is my first project. But I couldn't found a solution to this, so thank you for the information and your help ;) I did exactly what you said, but I can't know return a ModelAndView in a request.

Answer (score 2):

Your controller should be a `@Controller` not a `@RestController`, otherwise the response will be returned as a string as you observe.

As mentioned already in the comments your custom configuration is not needed at all, you could have a look at the sample provided by the `Spring boot` team https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp.

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't the main problem at the end. In fact I don't know what problem was, but finally I solved it reading more Spring Boot documentation first (or re-reading it), and using Thymeleaf. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
It happens when you have your jsp in directory which is handled by **ResourceHandler**:

```
 registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
```

This is only for static recourses - img, css, js.
You should move your jsp outside